# Excel concatenation logical conditions in IF statement

Tags: excel

How do I concatenate several conditions in Excel in the IF statement? I want to compare values in 2 different columns but mith more than 1 condition!. IF (condition 1,condition2 ; truevalue;) i dont know the sintaxis for this!

Answer (score 0):

If you use purely native worksheet functions, you have to nest your `if` statements.  It's far from ideal:

```
=if(condition1,X,if(condition2,Y,if(condition3,Z,A)))
```

Is like saying:

```
if (condition1) then X
else if (condition2) then Y
else if (condition3) then Z
else A
```

You can also define a User Defined Function (UDF) using VBA, but that has some disadvantages associated with it.  It adds a lack of transparency for those who don't use VBA.  It also makes your workbook a little more "suspicious" since it has embedded macros, which is a turn off for some.

Depending on how complex your conditions are, a UDF still may be the way to go.

Post some real pseudo-code to help identify which side you fall on.